# Floating point number taking an unexpectedly high value

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point

I have written a c-script that produces a text file for another application. A floating point number 'b' gets a very high value and i'm not sure why. I have an almost identical file in which this doesn't happen. I am new to C so any help would be appreciated - I appreciate that this may be a very simple error. The code is below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define LARGESTR 1000
#define INITIALTIME 40

void clear_string(char *s,int l)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        s[i]='\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[LARGESTR];
    int ramp_flow = 5, car_count_seg1 = 45, car_count_seg2 = 45, car_count_seg3 = 45, fw_upstream_queue = 20, onramp_queue = 60, a;
    float outflow_count, percentout = 0.7, b;

    //Total Input to system
    for(a=(INITIALTIME + 10); a<(INITIALTIME + 250); a+=10) {
        if((a>=10) && (a<600)) {
            b=b+1.39+0.556;
        }
        if((a>=600) && (a<1200)) {
            b=b+(((a*9.167)-5000)/360)+(((a*1.67)-800)/360);
        }
        if((a>=1200) && (a<2700)) {
            b=b+16.67+3.33;
        }
        if((a>=2700) && (a<3300)) {
            b=b+(((a*(-10))+33000)/360)+(((a*(-2))+6600)/360);
        }
        if((a>=3300) && (a<4800)) {
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n", b);
    b = b + car_count_seg1 + car_count_seg2 + car_count_seg3 + fw_upstream_queue + onramp_queue;
    printf("%f\n", b);
    outflow_count = b*percentout;
    printf("%f\n", outflow_count);

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("1rampproblem.pddl","w+");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"\n(define (problem trafficjuncprob)\n(:domain traffic-junction)\n(:objects)\n(:init");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (outflow-count) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (critical-density) 45)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maximum-density) 270)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maximum-flow) 20)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (time) %d)",INITIALTIME);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (zero) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (toggle) 1)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (count) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (ramp-flow) %d)",ramp_flow);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (ramp-flow-realised) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (car-count-seg1) %d)",car_count_seg1);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (car-count-seg2) %d)",car_count_seg2);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (car-count-seg3) %d)",car_count_seg3);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maxflow-0-1) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maxflow-1-2) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maxflow-2-3) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (maxflow-3-4) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (flow-0-1) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (flow-1-2) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (flow-2-3) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (flow-3-4) 0)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (fw-upstream-queue) %d)",fw_upstream_queue);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(= (onramp-queue) %d)",onramp_queue);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n)\n\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(:goal (> (outflow-count) %f)\n)\n", outflow_count);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    clear_string(buffer,LARGESTR);
    sprintf(buffer,"(:metric minimize (total-time))\n)");
    fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I print the value of 'b' after the first for-loop and it is very large here

Comment: I mean a c program. I also know what c is I have coded using it several times before - I am just stuck on this problem. Not everyone is an expert. You have to start somewhere

Comment: Ignoring the difference between a compiled language and an interpreted language requires you stop writing programs and start learning and understanding these concepts.

Answer (score 4):

There is no initalizer for `b` in its declaration:

```
float outflow_count, percentout = 0.7, b;
```

so its value before the first use is whatever happened to be left in the stack by some previous use of that word. Each subsequent value depends on its initial value, so there is no basis for expecting to have any particular value.

I suggest initializing it.

The rest of this is tips on how to ask. The first thing you should have done is to strip out everything in your program that is not needed to reproduce the bug. Since the problem is present when you print `b` after the first loop, I removed everything after that, and then removed the declarations that became unreferenced as a result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LARGESTR 1000
#define INITIALTIME 40

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    float b;

    //Total Input to system
    for(a=(INITIALTIME + 10); a<(INITIALTIME + 250); a+=10) {
        if((a>=10) && (a<600)) {
            b=b+1.39+0.556;
        }
        if((a>=600) && (a<1200)) {
            b=b+(((a*9.167)-5000)/360)+(((a*1.67)-800)/360);
        }
        if((a>=1200) && (a<2700)) {
            b=b+16.67+3.33;
        }
        if((a>=2700) && (a<3300)) {
            b=b+(((a*(-10))+33000)/360)+(((a*(-2))+6600)/360);
        }
        if((a>=3300) && (a<4800)) {
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

In this stripped down program the problem is even more obvious.

Your problem report should have contained a stripped down program with only the relevant code, the expected value of `b`, why you expected it, and what you actually got.

Comment: suggest? if the value is uninitialized the program will behave unexpectedly, so accessing uninitialized values is a major issue, suggesting is very weak I would say `you must initialize it`. But still +1 for answering a post which claims that the `c-script` isn't working, this OP shouldn't be messing with a real programming language like c.

Comment: Also, you might **suggest** using compiler warnings, because this kind of problem may happen to anyone, unless they use compiler warnings and get notified before compilation is finished.

Comment: @iharob There are alternatives, such as dropping `b` from the right hand side of each assignment, and ensuring there is an assignment to it in every path. However, the simplest and safest change in this case is to initialize it, so that is what I am recommending.

Comment: I didn't mean that, i meant accessing the uninitialized value is a problem, how it gets initialized doesn't matter.